# iTerm2 – scroll less output with mouse

Tags: macos, terminal, scroll, mouse, iterm

I just switched from OSX Terminal to iTerm2, and I seem to have lost one piece of functionality.
In Terminal, I could **scroll through output of the `less` command** with my mouse, because I had installed [MouseTerm](https://bitheap.org/mouseterm/).

However, when I try scrolling `less` output in iTerm2, the window's scrollbar moves instead.
Strangely, scrolling works as expected with `vim`.

**How can I scroll `less` output with my mouse in iTerm2?**

Comment: It sounds like you have some sort of third-party software installed, because Terminal doesn’t have support for sending input to the tty when you use the mouse to scroll—it only knows how to scroll the scrollbar.

Comment: @ChrisPage Indeed, good spot. I forgot I had installed [MouseTerm](https://bitheap.org/mouseterm/) long ago. I clarified this in the question.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The iTerm2 issue is now marked as "fixed" -
but the fix is to add a hidden option, so it is not immediately obvious
how to enable the new `AlternateMouseScroll` option.

As Filippo Valsorda (author of the patch) [writes](https://filippo.io/native-scrolling-and-iterm2/),
once you install a nightly build (still not present in 1.0.0.20140629) of iTerm2,
just run this command:

```
$ defaults write com.googlecode.iterm2 AlternateMouseScroll -bool true
```

restart iTerm2, and all your windows will report scroll events as up/down arrow-key escapes
when the terminal is in the "alternate screen" (direct addressing) mode
used by programs like less, vim, emacs, etcetera.

For applications like vim and emacs that provide additional mouse support,
you will still want to enable mouse reporting mode,
as this automatic mode switch only enables scrolling.

Comment: Awesome! Except this doesn't work when inside of `tmux`. `less` inside of `tmux` has it responding as it usually does where the scroll will access the tmux pane history. Scratching my head a little bit. I can't look into this now but I wonder if there's a way to tell `tmux` to treat `less` in a special way. I think it's that tmux believes (correctly...) that less doesn't process the mouse wheel, and so it continues to override wheel functionality.

Comment: Per the comments at Filippo Valsorda's [original post](https://filippo.io/my-remote-shell-session-setup/) I suspect that you need to add ``set-window-option -g mode-mouse on`` to your ``~/.tmux.conf`` file.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I have iTerm 2.1.1 and I've tried all here says.

Comment: In Vim on iTerm2, I just scrolled up and down with the mouse wheel (didn't work), then tapped the up and down arrow keys, and a little notice popped up at the top of the window asking me if I wanted the mouse wheel to scroll in graphical programs.  Clicked yes and everything is peachy.  Nice.  :)

Answer (score 82):

Now it is implemented in iTerm2 and can be activated by

**Settings** -> **Advanced** -> **Scroll wheel sends arrow keys when in alternate screen mode** and change it to  **Yes**

[image: image of "Scroll wheel sends arrow keys when in alternate screen mode" setting]

(`defaults write com.googlecode.iterm2 AlternateMouseScroll -bool true` still works but it just changes the same setting)

Comment: One of SE's greatest weaknesses is that there's not a reliable mechanism to promote more up-to-date answers like this here, unless a lot of people vote or the OP comes back and changes the accepted answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on iterm2 build 3.1.5, any clues?

Comment: @dongiulio tried restarting the terminal and or mac?

Comment: in iTerm2 3.1.5 this solution works perfectly, and no restarts are required

Comment: Worked at the beginning, but not anymore. Using v3.1.7. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @Jonauz Try updating and or restarting iTerm, it works perfectly fine for me on v3.2.0

Comment: Doesn't work on 3.2.6 when while using git diff. Any suggestions?

Comment: Git defaults to setting `less -FRSX`, where -X disables this scroll-wheel behavior (for some reason). You can enable scrolling by setting the git pager with `git config --global core.pager 'less -FRS'`

Answer (score 3):

Finally did it, I've been spending a lot of time on this looking here and there with no luck, the simplest steps are:

1. **Install the 2.9 beta version**
2. Done

Answer (score 1):

This isn't implemented as of now.

There is an open issue in the iTerm 2 issue tracker about implementing it.

Comment: Yep, that was added in response to my question here and on the iTerm2 mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

Not the OP's question, but for anyone here trying to get this to work in tmux, with credit to [choco](https://github.com/choco) via [this github comment](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/157#issuecomment-150612608) here's a snippet to add to your tmux.conf to get it to handle alternate screens (e.g. less, vim) correctly:

```
# Check if copy-mode or any mouse flags, then send mouse events
# or check if we're in alternate screen end send navigation keys (up, down)

bind -n WheelUpPane if-shell -Ft='#{?pane_in_mode,1,#{mouse_any_flag}}' \
        'send -Mt=' 'if-shell -Ft= "#{alternate_on}" \
        "send -t= Up" "copy-mode -et= ; send -Mt="'
bind -n WheelDownPane if-shell -Ft= '#{?pane_in_mode,1,#{mouse_any_flag}}' \
        'send -Mt=' 'if-shell -Ft= "#{alternate_on}" \
        "send -t= Down" "send -Mt="'
```

Note, this doesn't require the [Iterm preference change mentioned in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37610820/197789), but it also isn't hurt by it.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of less supports the `--mouse` and related flags so there's no need send arrow keys to alternate screens.