# mouse capturing differences between Terminal.app with MouseTerm SIMBL plugin and iTerm2

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm, terminal-emulator, iterm2

iTerm2:

Mouse reporting works out of the box, works in Vim, works fully in Tmux, mouse wheel reporting works in Vim and for navigating Tmux history, but **mouse wheel reporting does not work in manpages, does not work in `git log`, does not work in `less`**

Terminal.app:

Mouse reporting does not work out of the box, but once installed mouse wheel reporting works everywhere including `less` and manpages and `git log`, etc. However mouse click+drag fails in Tmux, but still works in Vim.

So I'd rather use just one of these terminal apps, and I am particularly digging the immense feature set of iTerm2 (e.g. mouse-over to select which term to input to beats the hell out of anything Tmux can offer since it is **zero** keys to switch contexts) so I'd prefer if I can get mouse wheel reporting working fully in those programs.

I am having a hard time trying to debug the terminal codes being sent because the only way I can intercept them is through Vim, (as ctrl+V followed by scroll in my terminal will just have it scroll the terminal buffer) but Vim seems to be doing everything correctly.

Update: According to mouseterm project, it seems to be using a feature called "Simulated mouse wheel scrolling" to scroll programs like `less`... maybe I can configure iTerm to do the same. Somehow. <s>I do believe PuTTY also accomplishes this, and I'd like to have *at least* the functionality I can get on Windows on the Mac...</s> Nope, I'm just spoiled by the neatness of MouseTerm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although less (which is also used in `git log`) does not use mouse reporting itself,
iTerm2 can be configured to send up/down-arrow escape codes for scrolling
(from mouse wheel or trackpad two-finger swipe)
and less understands those.

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24695541/18829)
to a related question about how to set this up for iTerm2.

Comment: Amazing! Exactly what I'm looking for! Bravo!

Answer (score 1):

`less` does not actually recognize any terminal mouse events. (As such, tools that use it, like `man` and `git log` will not recognize mouse events either.) Something else you've done must be making it *appear* to support mouse events.

If you want the mouse wheel to work in your pager, you'll need to find a pager other than `less` which supports it. You might be able to put something together using `view` (`vim` in read-only mode), but applications like `man` which output content with control codes will be an issue there.

Comment: Indeed it looks like the way to replicate this behavior would be to get iTerm to detect when `less` is running and issue navigation keys based on scrolling. Not sure if that's configurable.

Comment: Another way to replicate this would be to patch (or rewrite) `less` to support mouse events. :)

Comment: That just sounds like a masochistic undertaking at least for me.

Comment: Oh hey! I just got an idea related to this. A program that transparently reads mouse events while sending back the output from less. in other words, a wrapper around less to make it translate mouse events into key events. I have no idea where to get started with this though.